# shell - remove numbers from a string column

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
SER1828-ZXC-A1-10002 
SER1878-IOP-B1-98989 
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWS_GH-A2-10301
SER1930-REM_PH-A2-10301
```

From above data my requirement is to remove any number form eg "ZXC-A1"..
output required is

```
SER1828-ZXC-A-10002
SER1878-IOP-B-98989
SER1930-QWE-A-10301
SER1930-QWE-A-10301
SER1930-QWS_GH-A-10301
SER1930-REM_PH-A-10301
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow sri. Please read h[ow to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Search and research - there are many regex examples on this site. Please show what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: yeah i have tried evrything

Comment: Include some examples it will influence who helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been more clearer when you raise the problem. Do not add test cases later

You can try this, I have modified the third field to last but one. But credit to @Kaz

```
~> more test
SER1828-ZXC-A1-10002
SER1878-IOP-B1-98989
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWS_GH-A2-10301
SER1930-REM_PH-A2-10301
SER1930-REM-SEW-PH-A2-10301
SER1940-REM-SPD-PL-D3-10301


~> awk -F- 'BEGIN { OFS="-" } { sub(/[0-9]/,"",$(NF-1)); print }' test
SER1828-ZXC-A-10002
SER1878-IOP-B-98989
SER1930-QWE-A-10301
SER1930-QWE-A-10301
SER1930-QWS_GH-A-10301
SER1930-REM_PH-A-10301
SER1930-REM-SEW-PH-A-10301
SER1940-REM-SPD-PL-D-10301
```

**Edit**

**Explanation**

```
-F- -> Define the input field separator 
OFS="-" ->  Set the output field separator 
sub( -> Substitute    
/[0-9]/ -> Select all the numbers 
"" -> substitute with nothing
$(NF-1) -> For the last but one field
Print -> Print All results
```

Comment: thanks a LOTTT...
could you please give the explanation for it,, please

Answer (score 1):

> *[I] have tried everything*

... except, say:

```
awk -F- 'BEGIN { OFS="-" } { sub(/[0-9]/,"",$3); print }' yourdata
```

Comment: Thanks... but my problem was this :-
SER1828-ZXC-A1-10002 
SER1878-IOP-B1-98989 
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWE-A2-10301
SER1930-QWS_GH-A2-10301
SER1930-REM_PH-A2-10301
SER1930-REM-SEW-PH-A2-10301
SER1940-REM-SPD-PL-D3-10301